# MongoDB aggregate conditional push with fixed array length

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Scenario: Members can choose (yes/no) from 4 different activities available.

Based on the following input,

```
[
 {
  name:"member1",
  activity:"activity1",
  selected:true
 },
 {
  name:"member1",
  activity: "activity3",
  selected:false
 },
 {
  name:"member2",
  activity:"activity2",
  selected:true
 },
 {
  name:"member2",
  activity: "activity4",
  selected:false
 }

]
```

need a result as follows, showing member's choice on all the 4 activities in the order of activity 1 to 4 (including the activities which the user has not made a decision yet)

```
   [
     {
      name:"member1",
      activities:[true,null,false,null]
     },
     {
      name:"member2",  
      activities:[null,true,null,false]
     }
    ]
```

I tried the following code,

```
   db.collection("MemberActivities").aggregate(
    [
        {
        $group:
            {
            _id: "$MemberName",
            activities: { $push: "$selected"}
            }
        }
    ]
```

but, it contain only the activities the user has made a decision (yes/no).

```
[
     {
      _id:"member1",
      activities:[true,false]
     },
     {
      _id:"member2",  
      activities:[true,false]
     } ]
```

Please guide on how to get desired result.